# Question posted in a language other than english and was closed. Should I translate it and vote to reopen it?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing

The question [¿Como puedo pasar de aplicación a externa (archivo)?Minecraft PE [closed]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/365133) was closed for being written in Spanish instead of English.

I know Spanish, so I can translate it into English. Should I do it and vote to reopen it or leave it closed?

Comment: I'd say do it. We're hesitant when people use Google Translate as it can be... less than accurate, but if you speak it natively I don't see why not. Perhaps just leave a comment explaining that you translated it manually.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9978/143571

Comment: @Wrigglenite I looked at that question before asking this one, but I didn't find anything about questions that are already closed but can be translated to be made on-topic.

Comment: Seems like a grey area to say the least.  Closing non-English posts has been the usual approach on this site, but now we are saying if you know the language you can translate it yourself and that is fine...? Not to discredit Lemon, but how do we know that they actually know Spanish? I will say that given how little non-English posts we do get, it's not really a big issue, but it really is a grey area.  It also puts a burden on the OP - what if they don't know English at all and we just translated their post and give English answers? Arguably that puts the OP in an even worse situation...

Comment: I think this is still an adequate duplicate: [What should we do with foreign language posts?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9978/what-should-we-do-with-foreign-language-posts)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, only the asker should translate their own posts. The question itself isn't the problem, it's communicating with the asker.

Once the post is translated, every other possible step of a question's lifetime could still create problems:

- Comments asking for details won't be understood or replied to
- Answers won't be understood, so the question has become useless to the OP
- The OP can no longer edit their post, as it is now in a language they don't understand. It's impossible to add new information to the question
- Should the question be closed, the OP won't know what to do in order to get it reopened

If you want to help, translating a question is not really providing that help. If someone can't communicate in the language required of everyone who joins the site, I'm afraid we can't do much for them.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my answer as I agree with everything you said. While I still believe the actions taken were fine (IMO), you bring up the valid point that even if we can understand the question, there is still the lack of communication with the OP.

Comment: I posted the question on the 14th and Robotnik said that there should not be any problems so I went ahead and translated it. Two days later I see this answer. Because I already translated it, should the edit be reverted or left as-is?

Comment: @Lemon I think the edit should be reverted, yes.